# Django model inheritance weird or expected behavior?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm currently working on a project using django 1.11 and struggled some time trying to find the cause of an error. I don't know if it's a bug or expected behavior and was hoping someone could shed some light into the issue or point me in the right direction. I already searched for similar issues but did not found anything similar.

The problem is the following, I have a base model class:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       if self.pk:
           self.modified_at = timezone.now
       return super(BaseModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

and it was working fine on every model, until I needed to override the default save behavior on another model:

```
class Agent(BaseModel):
    TIME_ZONES = [(tz, tz) for tz in pytz.common_timezones]

    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='agent',
    )

    time_zone = models.CharField(choices=TIME_ZONES,
                                 default=settings.TIME_ZONE,
                                 max_length=100)

    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.email = self.user.email
        return super(Agent, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

When I tried to save a new instance of the `Agent` model to the db doing `Agent(user=user).save()`, an exception was raised saying `expected string or bytes-like object`.

The exception is not raised if I do one of the following things:

- Change the `Agent` model to inherit directly from `models.Model` and declare the 'created_at`and`modified_at`in the`Agent` class
- Change the super call on the save method of the `Agent` class to `super(BaseModel, self).super(*args, **kwargs)` and still inheriting from `BaseModel`

As I said before, I don't know if I'm missing something and this is expected behavior or it is a bug. Thanks in advance for your help.

The full traceback is this:

```
Traceback:  

File "/root/.virtualenvs/ve/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/root/.virtualenvs/ve/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/root/.virtualenvs/ve/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/root/.virtualenvs/ve/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/root/.virtualenvs/ve/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/root/.virtualenvs/ve/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/root/.virtualenvs/ve/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py" in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
76.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/root/.virtualenvs/ve/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
63.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/var/task/backend/users/views/sign_up.py" in dispatch
19.         return super(SignUpViewSet, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

File "/root/.virtualenvs/ve/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
483.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "/root/.virtualenvs/ve/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in handle_exception
443.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "/root/.virtualenvs/ve/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
480.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/root/.virtualenvs/ve/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py" in post
192.         return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/var/task/backend/users/views/sign_up.py" in create
31.         user = self.perform_create(serializer)

File "/var/task/backend/users/views/sign_up.py" in perform_create
41.         user = serializer.save(self.request)

File "/var/task/backend/users/serializers/sign_up.py" in save
40.         agent.save()

File "/var/task/backend/users/models/agent.py" in save
31.         return super(Agent, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

File "/var/task/backend/core/models.py" in save
69.         return super(BaseModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

File "/root/.virtualenvs/ve/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
806.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "/root/.virtualenvs/ve/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
836.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)

File "/root/.virtualenvs/ve/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
903.                                       forced_update)

File "/root/.virtualenvs/ve/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_update
953.         return filtered._update(values) > 0

File "/root/.virtualenvs/ve/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _update
661.         return query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(CURSOR)

File "/root/.virtualenvs/ve/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
1191.         cursor = super(SQLUpdateCompiler, self).execute_sql(result_type)

File "/root/.virtualenvs/ve/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
863.             sql, params = self.as_sql()

File "/root/.virtualenvs/ve/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in as_sql
1157.                 val = field.get_db_prep_save(val, connection=self.connection)

File "/root/.virtualenvs/ve/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_db_prep_save
766.                                       prepared=False)

File "/root/.virtualenvs/ve/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_db_prep_value
1455.             value = self.get_prep_value(value)

File "/root/.virtualenvs/ve/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_prep_value
1434.         value = super(DateTimeField, self).get_prep_value(value)

File "/root/.virtualenvs/ve/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_prep_value
1292.         return self.to_python(value)

File "/root/.virtualenvs/ve/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in to_python
1395.             parsed = parse_datetime(value)

File "/root/.virtualenvs/ve/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/dateparse.py" in parse_datetime
94.     match = datetime_re.match(value)

Exception Type: TypeError at /api/v1/auth/sign-up/
Exception Value: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: "it was working fine on every model" => well obviously not, cf the accepted answer.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers turns out that the other models are using another parent class and the other one inheriting from BaseModel was calling the super bypassing the save method on the BaseModel class. That code was written by someone else, but not seeing this was entirely my fault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
self.modified_at = timezone.now
```

This is your problem. You meant to do `timezone.now()`. It's crashing when parsing the date from a function reference instead of a string or a datetime object. You don't trigger the behavior if you bypass the save method from the `BaseModel` class.

Comment: Oh, I feel like a fool now, guess that I was to tired to note that, thank you very much!